# WordPress Taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать кнопку "Посмотреть больше" текущей категории на новой странице, и так для всех стран. Помогите, пожалуйста, уже не могу, ну никак не получается. Заранее спасибо.

```html
<h1>SPA</h1>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
 array_merge(
  array(
  'post_type' => 'countries',
     'tour-type'    => 'spa'
  ), // это параметр который добавили мы
  $wp_query->query // это массив базового запроса текущей страницы
 )
);
  

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>



 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
 

<?php endwhile;
endif;
 
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
 <script>
 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
 var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
 var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
 var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
 </script>
 <div id="true_loadmore">Загрузить ещё</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, вам надо привести код.

Comment: Ээээ, погодите, а где js код и ajax? Кнопки Load More делают именно так.

Comment: Я хотел бы вывести на новую страницу возможно ли так

Comment: Судь в том что хочу на главном странице страны к примеру Италия выводились все категории по 4 статьи (категория кухня = 4, категория природа = 4, категория достопримечательности = 4) но при клике на категорию к примеру природа выводила всю природу связанную с этой страной, и так для всех стран. Спасибо за отклик

Comment: Ну и сделайте переход на другую страницу, где быдут выведена вся природа, скажем. Если хотите без обновления страницы - читайте про ajax.

Comment: Но при клике на категорию природу выводит все поты природ связанных с разными странами, а мне бы хотелось именно для текущей страны

Comment: Я в вашем коде вижу только ссылки на конкретные посты. При чем тут категории. Покажите на картинке, на что вы кликаете, приведите код, в котором бы присутствовала эта `<a...>`, тогда вам что-то посоветуют.

Comment: Правильно у меня только ссылки на конкретные посты, но добавить ссылку или кнопку на посмотреть больше на новую страницу не получается

Comment: Что мешает вывести html-код <a>? Не понимаю вашей проблемы

Comment: Я изменил код посмотрите пожалуйста. Там где идёт ajax выводит ещё посты но не могу выводить все эти посты на новую страницу чтобы посты категории природа выводилось на новую страницу